Powershell: Search supporting document for each event
I have a script in powershell to extract and subsequently display the path to the supporting document for a series of events, but it is not working as expected.
The document in question exists, I gave it the correct path, but the script refuses to do that row with the green highlight next to the file path. Please help me with this.
Example to understand the context: an event has a date, a document number and a partner name. In the document folder, there is the document as the following name: year month day_FF last 4 digits of the document number_NAME PARTNER (usually the first word).
$MainFolder = "FolderWithDocuments"
$ExcelFilePath = "EXCEL.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$StartRow = 1
$EndRow = 2
$ExcelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelApp.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilePath)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($SheetName)

$FolderPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $MainFolder -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
$FoundFiles = @{}

Function Search-PDF {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]]$FolderPaths,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$DocNumber,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [datetime]$DocDate,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Partner
    )

    $FormattedDate = $DocDate.ToString("yyyy MM dd")
    $LastTwo = $DocNumber.Substring([Math]::Max(0, $DocNumber.Length - 2))
    $LastThree = $DocNumber.Substring([Math]::Max(0, $DocNumber.Length - 3))
    $LastFour = $DocNumber.Substring([Math]::Max(0, $DocNumber.Length - 4))
    $SearchNumbers = @($LastTwo, $LastThree, $LastFour)

    $PartnerWords = $Partner -split ' '

    foreach ($FolderPath in $FolderPaths) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter "*.pdf" | ForEach-Object {
            $FileName = $_.Name

            $NumberMatch = $false
            foreach ($Num in $SearchNumbers) {
                if ($FileName -match "\b${Num}\b") {
                    $NumberMatch = $true
                    break
                }
            }

            if ($NumberMatch) {
                if ($FileName -match $FormattedDate) {
                    $PartnerMatch = $false
                    foreach ($Word in $PartnerWords) {
                        if ($FileName -match [regex]::Escape($Word)) {
                            $PartnerMatch = $true
                            break
                        }
                    }

                    if ($PartnerMatch) {
                        return $_.FullName
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $null
}

for ($Row = $StartRow; $Row -le $EndRow; $Row++) {
    try {
        $DocDate = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 1).Text
        $DocType = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 2).Text
        $DocNumber = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 3).Text
        $Partner = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 11).Text

        $DocDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($DocDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null)

        if (-not $DocNumber -or -not $Partner) {
            continue
        }

        $FoundFilePath = Search-PDF -FolderPaths $FolderPaths -DocNumber $DocNumber -DocDate $DocDate -Partner $Partner

        if ($FoundFilePath) {
            $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FoundFilePath)
            $Valid = $false

            if ($FileName -match $FormattedDate -and 
                ($FileName -match "\b${DocNumber}\b") -and 
                ($FileName -match [regex]::Escape($Partner))) {
                    $Valid = $true
            }

            if ($Valid) {
                $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 5).Value = $FoundFilePath
                $Worksheet.Rows.Item($Row).Interior.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(144, 238, 144).ToArgb()
                $FoundFiles[$FoundFilePath] = $true
            }
            else {
                $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 5).Value = "File found but does not meet the criteria."
                $Worksheet.Rows.Item($Row).Interior.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 99, 71).ToArgb()
            }
        }
        else {
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 5).Value = "No supporting document found."
            $Worksheet.Rows.Item($Row).Interior.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 99, 71).ToArgb()
        }

        Write-Host "Saving file after processing row $Row"
        $Workbook.Save()
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error processing row ${Row}: ${_}"
        $Workbook.Save()  
    }
}

$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
$ExcelApp.Quit()

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Worksheet) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelApp) | Out-Null

Write-Output "Script completed successfully."

When I run it, I don't get any errors, it checks line by line but, even though the document exists in the chosen folder, it refuses to find them.

Using Powershell extension in VS Code you can debug your Powershell script, and find out why the document cannot be found.  Without the same input that you are using, it would be hard to test.

Can you show us more of the files (real but sanitized examples of their filenames) you are searching for? What happens when your function Search-PDF finds multiple files that match the criteria? As it is now, that function will only return the first possible hit..

First of all hello.
@Theo, in excel, each row is like this: on column A is given as day/month/year, on column C the document number and on K is the name of the partner.
01.02.2024 - 4445 - STACK. The file for this event will be this: 2024 02 01_FF 4445_STACK.pdf.
@ Luuk, can you be a little more explicit please?
Thank you.

PS: Each event will have only one corresponding document. There are not 2 events with the same document, even if they are similar either in the combination of 2,3 or 4 digits, or in the date, or in the name.

You have $EndRow set to 2 only reading in the for loop rows 1 and 2 (less than or equal to 2).

All the extra explanation should be don using [edit] in the question, not via comments on that question.

@bogdannnn: Debugging is quit easy, you can step through your code, and check/verify values of different variables, to see if they match your expected value. (see screenshot: https://i.sstatic.net/fXAUgf6t.png )

I believe there is room for improvement by creating a better file filter for the Get-ChildItem cmdlet. Also, by doing that, there is no more need for the $FolderPaths = ... line in your code.
Try this:
$MainFolder       = "FolderWithDocuments"
$ExcelFilePath    = "SupportingPartnerFiles.xlsx"  # full absolute file path and name
$SheetName        = "Sheet1"
$StartRow         = 1
$EndRow           = 2
$ExcelApp         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelApp.Visible = $false  # $false is a lot faster
$Workbook         = $ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilePath)
$Worksheet        = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($SheetName)

function Search-PDF {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$DocNumber,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 2)]
        [datetime]$DocDate,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 3)]
        [string]$Partner
    )

    # create a regex for the last 4, 3 or 2 digits of the document number
    $lastDigits = (4..2 | ForEach-Object { ($DocNumber.Trim() -replace ".*(.{$_})", '$1') }) -join '|'
    $partnerIDs = @($Partner -split '\s+' -ne '')            # split the possible partner names into an array
    $filter     = '{0:yyyy MM dd}_FF *_*.pdf' -f $DocDate    # combine known parts to create a file filter

    # Try and find the first file that matches the criteria
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $filter -Recurse -File | Where-Object {
                ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1] -in $partnerIDs -and     # partner name in the $partnerIDs array ?
                ($_.BaseName -split '_')[1] -match "($lastDigits)$"   # document number ok ?
            } | Select-Object -First 1
    if ($file) { 
        # success, output the FullName
        $file.FullName 
    }
}

for ($Row = $StartRow; $Row -le $EndRow; $Row++) {
    try {
        $DocDate   = [datetime]::ParseExact($Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 1).Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null)
        $DocNumber = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 3).Text
        $Partner   = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 11).Text

        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($DocNumber) -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Partner)) {
            continue
        }
        # try and find the supporting file using the specified criteria
        $FoundFilePath = Search-PDF -Path $MainFolder -DocNumber $DocNumber -DocDate $DocDate -Partner $Partner

        if ($FoundFilePath) {
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 5).Value = $FoundFilePath
            $Worksheet.Rows.Item($Row).Interior.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(144, 238, 144).ToArgb()
        }
        else {
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Row, 5).Value = "No supporting document found."
            $Worksheet.Rows.Item($Row).Interior.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 99, 71).ToArgb()
            Write-Warning "No supporting document found for row $Row"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning ('Error processing row {0}: {1}'-f $Row, $_.Exception.Message)
    }
}

$Workbook.Close($true)  # close and save the changes
$ExcelApp.Quit()

# clean-up memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelApp) 
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Write-Host "Script completed successfully."

